# Configuration for HTTP only ALB ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to deploy a rule in  my ALB ingress, which is controlled by ALB Ingress Controller in an EKS. It should route traffic on a certain path to a service only on HTTP. Header value is the second condition (Cloudfront scenario). My configuration is successfully deployed, but no listener rule for port 80 is created.

This is my config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-fallback
  namespace: {{.Values.namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-lb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.wordpress: |
      [{"Field":"http-header","HttpHeaderConfig":{"HttpHeaderName": "header", "Values":["value"]}}]

spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /path/
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Values.name }}
                port:
                  name: http
```

What is missing here for it to work?